# Slimpicker date issue with format

Tags: javascript, slimpicker

I have this slimpicker installed, well i'm using it.

The idea is:
I have a problem with the selection of the year, if i choose 2012 i get something like:
dd/mm/112

If i choose 2013 though i get:
dd/mm/2013

This is strange.
This are the data for the js:

```
dayChars: 1,
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        daysInMonth: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], // Leap year is added later
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',                                          // How the output looks after selection
        yearStart: (new Date().getFullYear()),                     // Default starting year for dropdown options is 5 years ago
        yearRange: 10,                                                 // Show a 10 year span
        yearOrder: 'asc',                                              // Counting up in years
        startDay: 7                       // 1 = week starts on Monday, 7 = week starts on Sunday
    },
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you read the value and getting wrong result?

Comment: It's ok from your code. http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/5DvfC/

Comment: yeah.. sorry.. thanks guys though

Answer (score 2):

Search for the code in your slimpicker.js would be as below

// The date to show on the calendar

```
this.currentYear = this.calendarYear = this.current.getYear();
this.currentMonth = this.calendarMonth = this.current.getMonth();
this.currentDay = this.current.getDate();
```

and change it as below

// The date to show on the calendar

```
this.currentYear = this.calendarYear = this.current.getFullYear();
this.currentMonth = this.calendarMonth = this.current.getMonth();
this.currentDay = this.current.getDate();
```